# Model attributes of data type short have leading zero's removed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm having an issue with my model removing leading zeros from attributes of data type 'short'.

So for example if I include this in my controller:

```
Purchase purchase = purchaseService.getById(purchaseId);
```

The expiry attribute shows a value of '612' when it should be '0612'.

Is there an annotaion I can add to prevent this? (I want to avoid adding any custom code to the getter to fix it).

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Purchase implements Serializable
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6603477834338392140L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "purchase", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Tag> tags;

    private Long pan;

    private short cvc;

    private short expiry;

    public short getExpiry()
    {
        return expiry;
    }

    public void setExpiry(short expiry)
    {
        this.expiry = expiry;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That short primitive type is just a number so the the leading '0' is insignificant. It will never store it.

It looks like you're storing an expiration date for a credit card.

When I did eCommerce apps we were not making decisions on that value so it was easiest for us to store that as a String which would preserve the leading '0'. Then we would transmit the String as entered to the CC Company.

If you need to do date arithmetic or comparisons, you could store that as a Date object which you could then print in any format you wanted. But be careful to determine whether 0612 means the first of July or the last of July. And don't forget that Java Dates are 0 indexed so when a user inputs 6 and means June you need to adjust that to create the Date object.

Comment: Thanks Speck. I'll probably just go with changing it to a String as it's not likely I'll be doing much with the value anyway. Useful info and advice :)